# How to call both takeWhile and dropWhile on the same Java Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

How do I combine [takeWhile](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#takeWhile(java.util.function.Predicate)) and [dropWhile](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#dropWhile(java.util.function.Predicate)) on the same Java Stream?

I would like to either use or implement something like Scala's [span](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.4/scala/collection/mutable/Iterable.html#span(p:A=%3EBoolean):(C,C)) method.

So far, I have the following code, but, as an exercise, I am trying to use Streams whenever possible):

```
Iterator<T> iter = ...
// takeWhile(pred).forEach(foo)
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    T elem = iter.next();
    if (!pred(elem)) {
        break;
    }
    foo(elem);
}
// dropWhile(pred).forEach(bar)
iter.forEachRemaining(elem -> bar(elem));
```

Comment: You can't use `takeWhile` and `dropWhile` for that.

Comment: You could do it on an `Iterable`, but not on a `Stream`, because a `Stream` is one-use only, while you can create multiple iterators from an `Iterable`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `takeWhile` and `dropWhile` for that on a `Stream`, because a `Stream` is one-use only, but you could do it on an `Iterable`, because you can create multiple iterators from an `Iterable`.

Depending on your needs, you can do what the shown logic is trying to do, i.e. perform one of two actions depending on when a condition is first true. You can write a helper method for that:

```java
static <T> Consumer<T> span(Predicate<T> p, Consumer<T> prefix, Consumer<T> suffix) {
    return new Consumer<>() {
        private boolean conditionMet;
        @Override
        public void accept(T t) {
            if (! conditionMet) {
                if (p.test(t)) {
                    prefix.accept(t);
                    return;
                }
                conditionMet = true;
            }
            suffix.accept(t);
        }
    };
}
```

You would then use it like this on a `Stream`:

```java
Stream<T> stream = ...;

stream.forEachOrdered(span(elem -> pred(elem),
                           elem -> foo(elem),
                           elem -> bar(elem)));

// Or the method reference version:
stream.forEachOrdered(span(MyClass::pred, MyClass::foo, MyClass::bar));
```

That would call `foo()` for each element while `pred()` returns true, then call `bar()` on all remaining elements.

Note that the entire concept of `span` requires ordered processing, defeating the stream advantage of parallel processing.